# What is the use of additional column of 1s in normal equation?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

Currently I am going through Normal Equation in Machine Learning.

$$ 
\hat\theta = (X^T \cdot X)^{-1} \cdot X^T \cdot y
$$

But when I see how they use this equation, I found they always add an additional column of 1s in the starting of matrix X before transposing.

I don't understand why. What's the logic behind this?

The places where I found such things

1) [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/2DKxQ/normal-equation) - Theory

2) Implementation

> Now let’s compute using the Normal Equation. We will use the `inv()`
>   function from NumPy’s Linear Algebra module (`np.linalg`) to compute the
>   inverse of a matrix, and the `dot()` method for matrix multiplication:
>
> `X_b = np.c_[np.ones(( 100, 1)), X] # add x0 = 1 to each instance`
>
> Géron, Aurélien. Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and
>   TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent
>   Systems (p. 111). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Comment: They represent intercept term, also called bias.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The normal equations are designed such that each coefficient in the model has an input of some kind it's being multiplied against. The column of ones is the "input" to the intercept term.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Are we adding a column of ones because of a convention? I'm asking, because it looks like any additional vector, not being a zero vector, would work.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to accommodate the bias. While finding the hypothesis function the bias or the y-intercept part is multiplied with 1 (column of 1) in the matrix multiplication.